# When Reading a file (system call), Why do I set buf to '\0'?

Tags: c, system-calls

I want to know why when we're reading a file do we have set the buf equal to *'\0'* before we can close fd?
I'll demonstrate in an example.

```
ssize_t read_textfile(const char *filename, size_t letters)
{
    int fd;
    int i, y;
    char *buf;
    if (!filename)
        return (0);
    fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0)
        return (0);
    buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * letters);
    if (!buf)
        return (0);
    i = read(fd, buf, letters);
    if (i < 0)
    {
        free(buf);
        return (0);
    }
    buf[i] = '\0';        // This is what I'm talking about
    close(fd);
    y = write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, i);
    if (y < 0)
    {
        free(buf);
        return (0);
    }
    free(buf);
    return (y);
}
```

Comment: For this code, you don't need that.  It will assist your debugger when displaying char buffers as terminated strings, but that's about it. If you were using any functions expecting terminated strings it would matter a great deal. You're not, so it doesn't.

Comment: What does the file contain? Is it a binary file or a text file? Does your course material suggest to watch the program in a debugger?

Comment: Unrelated, but `return` is NOT a function... The parentheses are pointless (and misleading)...

Comment: As @Paul Lynch points out in his answer, you want to `malloc( sizeof( char ) * (letters + 1) );` if you still want to punch that 0 into `buf[ i ]`...

Comment: @Fe2O3 ... or just `malloc( letters + 1 ) ;` since `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition.

Comment: Presumptuous. In fact I was lazy... Should be `malloc( sizeof buf[ 0 ] * (letters + 1) );` Better habit than "knowing" the size of the datatype (like '1')... Fewer mishaps down the road... (I've never worked with 'em, but there are 'wide' characters out in the world.)

Comment: @chux - it's been a long day!

Comment: @Fe2O3 : the fact that `sizeof(char) == 1` is not "presumptuous", that the type of `buf` will always be  `char*` is and `char *buf = malloc( sizeof(*buf) * (letters + 1) );` is what I would suggest - no need to leave that pointer dangling or even declare it so far from point of use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you think it's necessary, but assuming the read() reads all letters (i == letters), buf[i] = '\0' overruns your buffer. And your input file is left open if the malloc() fails.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to and you do not need it in this code.,

This line makes a C string (adding null terminating character). As you use `write` you do not need it, but if you use any function taking string as a parameter you will need it.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the only use of `buf` after the "termination" is the `write` call and that writes `buf[0]` to `buf[i-1]`, then the character at `buf[i]` is ignored.  As such the "termination" serves no purpose at all.

Not only does it serve no purpose, it is in fact also a bug.  If the file contains at least `letters` bytes, then `i == letters` and `buf[i]` will be out of bounds.